# Atomic update column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I am using MS SQL Server, and I have a table. I want each SQL Server client to acquire one row and update it, so that the client knows that only he acquired that record, and no one else!

```
record1 a b c 0
record2 d e f 0
...
```

One client should acquire and update last value from 0 to 1.

The solution should work at least from SQL Server 2005 and above.

```
ATOMIC
{
    select top 1 * from table where column='0' // get one row where column is '0'
    update table set column='1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
update top (1) table with (readpast)
set Column1=1
output inserted.*
where Column1 = 0
```

Which should do it all in one go. You only need the [`readpast`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint if, having acquired the unique value, the connection keeps a transaction open for a long period of time. If you're *just* doing the update you can omit it.

Comment: But is there a way to get the other columns from each record? a, d ... are some GUIDs and I need them... Besides updating I need to know the value of ther columns for that record.

Comment: That's what `output inserted.*` is giving you - this `UPDATE` will return a result set containing *all* of the columns from `table`. If you wanted to be more selective, you can name individual columns - `output inserted.column1, inserted.column4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update a table through a Common Table Expression.

Below I create a CTE that picks just one row and then that is used in the UPDATE.

```
WITH
  singleRow AS
(
  select top 1 * from table where column='0'
)
UPDATE
  singleRow
SET
  column= '1'
;
```

***NOTE:*** Remember to ensure any preceding commands are terminated with a `;`, else the `WITH` syntax doesn't work.

Comment: But is there a way to get the other columns from each record? a, d ... are some GUIDs and I need them...